# Unable to maintain strings saved in 2D char array when function is exited

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I am trying to save Strings in an array of char pointers. Unfortunately when I return to the main and try to print the contents of the array the value's are not as expected.

I am looking to save encoding's for all the ASCII values so I can encode a file. It is based on the Huffman tree but I have omitted unrelated code.

Part of the main concerned

```
char ** encodings;
encodings = calloc(256, sizeof(char*));
walk_tree(root,)
```

The function where I am saving the encodings

```
void walk_tree(struct huffnode * root, char * encoding, char ** encodingsArray)
{
    if(root->is_leaf)
    {
        encodingsArray[root->c] = encoding;
        puts(encodingsArray[root->c]) // this prints valid value
    }
    else
    {
        char temp [256];          //below is code to get the encodings, dont worry about it
        strcpy(temp, encoding);
        strcat(temp, "0");
        walk_tree(root->left, temp, encodingsArray);
        //go right
        strcpy(temp, encoding);
        strcat(temp, "1");
        walk_tree(root->right, temp, encodingsArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: `encodingsArray[root->c] = encoding;` --> `encodingsArray[root->c] = strdup(encoding);`

Comment: **hero** that worked to solve it. Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`encodingsArray[root->c] = encoding;` --> `encodingsArray[root->c] = strdup(encoding);`
                    – BLUEPIXY